# Objective C: Search in a tableview with NSASCIIStringEncoding

Tags: xcode, search

I am searching into a `UITableView` using this:

```
titles = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[datamanager titlesForEntriesBetween:(NSInteger)[slider minSelectedValue] and:(NSInteger)[slider maxSelectedValue]containing:searchText]];
```

How can I encode array value with `NSASCIIStringEncoding` during the search process?

(Array contains `"tête"` for example.. and when I search `"tete"` nothing matches.. so I will encode array value just for my search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add change the third parameter to your datamanager function:

```
- (NSArray*)titlesForEntriesBetween:(NSInteger)startIndex
  and:(NSInteger)stopIndex
  withFunction:(BOOL(^)(NSString*))block {
  NSMutableArray *retVal = [NSMutableArray array];
  for(NSInteger i = startIndex; i <= stopIndex; ++i) {
    NSString *string = [array_ objectAtIndex:i];
    if (block(string)) {
      [retVal insertObject:string];
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

And then I would call the function like this:

```
titles = [datamanager titlesForEntriesBetween:(NSInteger)[slider minSelectedValue] and:(NSInteger)[slider maxSelectedValue] withFunction:^(BOOL)(NSString *str) {
  NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  NSString *simpleString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data usingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
  return [simpleString isEqualToString:str];
}]];
```

Note: I just typed this in, I haven't tried to compile/run this.